# checking if 2 equations is bigger than 0

Tags: java

```
if((quantity1[k].getrestmass() - cold[i].getmass()) > 0 
   && (quantity1[k].getrestvolym() - cold[i].getvolym()) > 0)
```

I want to compare these arguments so that both these numbers are > 0, but I'm getting a null pointer exception.

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
>       at Main.main(Main.java:88)

Comment: How can we know what's wrong with it? Please add any errors you get and an expected output for a certain input.

Comment: The IF itself looks fine to me

Comment: What is on the line 88?

Comment: quantity1[k] or  cold[i] or quantity1[k].getrestmass() or cold[i].getmass() or quantity1[k].getrestvolym() or cold[i].getvolym() or something else is null...